# Python flask api for mongodb error 404

Tags: python, json, mongodb, rest, flask

I have written a rest api using python flask with mongodb and implemented a client device program that communicates with the server app but keeps getting error 404 from the web app. For some reason, I'm having a hard time getting my python server to cooperate. What I am trying to do is fetch all JSON data from a mongodb collection that is formatted as such:

```
{
    Results:
        {'time1': 'TIME1_STR', 'temp1': 'TEMP1_STR'}
        {'time2': 'TIME2_STR', 'temp2': 'TEMP2_STR'}
        {'time3': 'TIME3_STR', 'temp3': 'TEMP3_STR'}
}`
```

I am able to iterate the list of entries if they contain the same object name such as time, which will return all contents of the collection with the object time. However, I need to return the objects time1, time2, and time3 and not all the objects with the name time. I haven't found a way to go about this that doesn't give me error 404. For example, the uncommented code returns all json object arrays by the object name temp1, however this doesn't allow me to get the entries for time2 and time3 arrays as given in the commented portion of the code. Can someone please help me make understand and fix this issue so that I can get my project working properly?

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from pprint import pprint

"""***************************** INITIALIZE *********************************"""

# Initialize Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure MongoDB
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://pkitsos:GoLobo$@localhost:27017/admin'

# Initialize MongoDB
mongo = PyMongo(app)


# [GET] retrieve list of logins
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_logins():
    thermo = mongo.db.thermo

    output = []

    # Find all queries in login collection
    for q in thermo.find():
        output.append({'time1': q['time1'], 'temp1': q['temp1']})
    """
    for q in thermo.find().limit(1):    
        output.append({'time2': q['time2'], 'temp2': q['temp2']})
    for q in thermo.find().limit(1):    
        output.append({'time3': q['time3'], 'temp3': q['temp3']})
    """
    return jsonify({'result' : output})
```

Comment: Could you try methods=["POST"] - I would be astonished if anything used 'get' for login!

Comment: @PaulaThomas Sorry, this isn't actually for a login. I just forgot to change the route name. I need the method to be GET so that I can get time and temp setpoints from the server for my client program to use.

Comment: The json that is shown as an example above is incorrect. Results should be defined as an array of documents. Something like "Results":[ {}, {}, {}]